# Why is the NA/NaN error delivered here, and what can I do about it?

Tags: r, dplyr

My data look like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  Type = c(rep("A", 2), rep("B", 2), rep("A", 2), rep("B", 2)),
  Source = c(rep("X", 4), rep("Y", 4)),
  ID = c(1001:1008),
  January = c(11, 22, 10, 30, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  February = c(10, 42, 15, 27, NA, NA, NA, NA) 
)
```

(In reality there are many more columns over multiple years, and some of them are non-NA in the Y rows. But this will do for my question.)

I want to make the manipulation...

```
newDF <- df %>%
  group_by(Type, Source) %>%
  summarize(theTotal = sum(January:February, na.rm = TRUE))
```

...but I get the error `Error in January:February : NA/NaN argument`. I know why I am getting this error: January and February are NA in some rows. I would get this error even if February had numbers in those rows, as long as January was still NA.

My questions are: 1) Why isn't `na.rm = TRUE` enough to prevent this from happening? 2) What, if anything, can I do to my code to make sure I get 0 for those combinations of A/B and Y?

Comment: `df%>%pivot_longer(January:February)%>%group_by(Type,Source)%>%summarise(theTotal = sum(value,na.rm=TRUE))` THIS CAN WORK TOO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, probably, we can use `summarise_at` and then create a single column with `sum`.  After `grouping_by` the columns of interest, we get the. `sum` of columns 'January' to 'February' as a single row. with `summarise_at` and then `ungroup` and get the `sum` again

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Type, Source) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(January:February), sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   transmute(Type, Source, 
    theTotal = rowSums(select(.,January:February), na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Type  Source theTotal
#   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#1 A     X            85
#2 A     Y             0
#3 B     X            82
#4 B     Y             0
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  group_split(Type, Source) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>%
           summarise(Type = first(Type),  Source = first(Source), 
theTotal = select(., January:February) %>% unlist %>% sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Type  Source theTotal
#  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#1 A     X            85
#2 A     Y             0
#3 B     X            82
#4 B     Y             0
```

Comment: Your dplyr example worked perfectly. But can you explain why my original code was not sufficient?

Comment: @mmyoung77 In your code, the `sum` is applied on range of column names which it can't evaluate